# How do you create a html Download link?

Tags: html

is it possible to make a html download link, without using a server?

I have made some games, and I want to upload my stuff to my website.

The file is a zip.

Please help!

Comment: Send the file in an email. Or run a server on your own system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, something needs to host the files (if you want to make the publicly available over the Internet).  You do not need to run the server yourself, so you may be able to use something like [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com).

If you just want to share the files with another person, you can look into other protocols (SMTP/email, FTP, etc.) but your best bet is probably to upload the files to a file hosting solution.

Comment: Or <strike>MegaUpload</strike>, http://www.rapidshare.com/ http://www.mediafire.com/

Comment: I think someone hacked into my account, I dont remember saying this question was answered.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you say "to my website", I assume you have a site. Upload the .zip file to your server, and then link to it with

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/myzipfile.zip">Download my ZIP file</a>
```

You can change the `href="{SOMETHING}"` to contain the link to your ZIP file, and the text "Download my ZIP file" to whatever you want the link to say.

Answer (score 0):

If your website is online, you can link directly to the file itself (be wary of exceeding your hostings bandwidth if the downloads pick up).

```
http://yourwebsite.com/yourzipfile.zip
```

and

```
<a href="http://yourwebsite.com/yourzipfile.zip" alt="">Your Link"</a>
```

You may need to purchase domain, hosting, and **do some additional research on this whole process of getting a website online**. You can use a web based FTP or a stand alone FTP client to upload your files onto a web server.